# How to run windows automation application in AWS window server

Tags: c#, wpf, automation

If I run window automation application in AWS window server, then `SendInput` or `SendKeys` method are not working. The message of below is recieved error message, when I call SendInput and Sendkeys method in WPF application on AWS window.

```
System.Exception: Some simulated input commands were not sent successfully. The most common reason for this happening are the security features of Windows including User Interface Privacy Isolation (UIPI). Your application can only send commands to applications of the same or lower elevation. Similarly certain commands are restricted to Accessibility/UIAutomation applications. Refer to the project home page and the code samples for more information.
   location: WindowsInput.WindowsInputMessageDispatcher.DispatchInput(INPUT[] inputs)
   location: WindowsInput.MouseSimulator.MoveMouseTo(Double absoluteX, Double absoluteY)
```

When the my window automation application is running without RDP Session. It crashes.
I think, It is related RDP session. If I'm connecting RDP Session, my application is working very well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should provide more information than "RDP session".

You are using native function, [SendInput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput).

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern UInt32 SendInput(UInt32 numberOfInputs, INPUT[] inputs, Int32 sizeOfInputStructure);
```

According to Microsoft document,

> The function returns the number of events that it successfully inserted into the keyboard or mouse input stream. If the function returns zero, the input was already blocked by another thread. To get extended error information, call `GetLastError`. This function fails when it is blocked by UIPI. Note that neither `GetLastError` nor the return value will indicate the failure was caused by UIPI blocking.

Please provide [`GetLastError`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-getlasterror) result.

You should call the `GetLastError` function immediately when a function's return value indicates that such a call will return useful data.

```
public void DispatchInput(INPUT[] inputs)
{
    if (inputs == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("inputs");
    if (inputs.Length == 0) throw new ArgumentException("The input array was empty", "inputs");

    try
    {
        var successful = NativeMethods.SendInput((UInt32)inputs.Length, inputs, Marshal.SizeOf(typeof (INPUT)));
    }
    catch
    {
        // if you execute any function that communicate with OS before here, LastError might be lost.
        error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
        Console.WriteLine("The last Win32 Error was: " + error);
    }
    
    if (successful != inputs.Length)
                throw new Exception("Some simulated input commands were not sent successfully. The most common reason for this happening are the security features of Windows including User Interface Privacy Isolation (UIPI). Your application can only send commands to applications of the same or lower elevation. Similarly certain commands are restricted to Accessibility/UIAutomation applications. Refer to the project home page and the code samples for more information.");
        }
```

Comment: No. you should exactly read my question. I said that "If I'm connecting RDP Session, my application is working very well. " ..

Comment: UIPI error is common reason when SendInput, SendKeys  was failed.

Comment: If you are sure this is not related with UIPI, then provide result of `GetLastError`.

Comment: I already known UIPI issue in automation application. It is not related my issue. My issue is related RDP session. Please read the my question. If my issue is related UIPI, then always not working in my aws server. But when I'm connecting my AWS server via RDP, application is working very very very well......

Comment: UIPI is simple common reason, when call SendKeys  or SendInput method. The common reason is not key in my question.

Comment: If your answer is right, then why my application is working when connected to AWS by RDP. Please tell me about your thinking. Your answer is good to me. but, I don't understand in your opinion.

Comment: @TaehyungKim I am not saying it is UIPI issue now. Just need more information to find out what causes your issue... Can you run `GetLastError` when `System.Exception` happened?

Comment: First, I set SetLasterError to true. When occurs this exception, I Call GetLastError API and then I received integer 0 value.

Comment: You should call the `GetLastError` function immediately.

Comment: Yes. I called immediately. But I always get 0 value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217961/discussion-between-ibocon-and-taehyung-kim).